# Batch command to check if given version of Oracle client is installed or not

Tags: batch-file

I want to pass Oracle client version as parameter to a batch script and find whether it is already installed or not. I am using the below code to verify :

```
REG Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE /F "12.1.0.2" /S
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (

ECHO ORACLE client already installed

) else (
ECHO Oracle not installed.
)
```

But the above code (REG QUERY) displays all the registry folders if that Oracle version is installed. I just want the ECHO messages to be displayed and also if the installed version is 32bit or 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
REG Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE /F "12.1.0.2" /S  >nul 2>nul && (
   ECHO ORACLE client already installed & rem
) || (
   ECHO Oracle not installed.
)
```

?

**edit** - checks also if 32b version is installed:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "installed= Oracle not installed."

REG Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE /F "12.1.0.2" /S  >nul 2>nul && (
    set "installed=ORACLE client already installed."
    rem
) 

REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE /F "12.1.0.2" /S  >nul 2>nul && (
    set "installed=ORACLE client already installed."
    rem
) 


echo %installed%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, how to check if it's 32bit or 64bit which was installed ?